Baby Rudin Theorem 9.7b: how to verify $\|A-B\|$ has the properties of a metric?
Baby Rudin Theorem 9.7:



where $L(R^n,R^m)$ is the set of all linear transformations of $R^n$ into $R^m$.
I need to prove the distance $\|A-B\|$ has the properties of a metric:
(a)  $ \quad d(p,q)>0$ if $p \neq q$ ; $d(p,p)=0$;
(b)  $ \quad d(p,q) = d(q,p)$;
(c)  $ \quad d(p,q) \le d(p,r)+d(r,q)$.
The part (b) and (c) have been proved.
As for the part (a), I need to show $\|A-B\|>0$ if $A \neq B$ and $A, B \in L(R^n,R^m)$, but the equality of two linear transformations has not been defined in the book. Does it mean $A = B \iff A\mathbf{x} = B\mathbf{x}$ for any $\mathbf{x} \in R^n$ ?

It is true since the domain is $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Linear transformations are functions. So yes, the equality $A=B$ means $Ax=Bx$ for all $x$.
